# Perl regexp substitution - multiple matches

Tags: regex, perl, string-substitution

Friends,

need some help with substitution regex.
I have a string

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

and I need to replace it by

```
;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;
```

I tried

```
s/;;/;\\N/;/g
```

but it gives me

```
;\N;;\N;;\N;;\N;;\N;;\N;;
```

tried to fiddle with lookahead and lookbehind, but can't get it solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you can't match twice the same character you approach doesn't work. To solve the problem you can only check the presence of a following ; with a lookahead (the second ; isn't a part of the match) :

```
s/;(?=;)/;\\N/g
```

Comment: this works very well. Thank a lot.  I knew look..... will do the trick only I had no experience with it. Until now :)

Comment: Yes, seems better than `s/(?<!^)(?=;)/\\N/g;`. 

Comment: @stribizhev: sometimes we need to resist to the madness of assertions.

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a regex for this, and instead make use of `split`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = ';;;;;;;;;;;;;'; 

print join ( '\N', split ( //, $str ) );
```

Splitting on nulls, to get each character, and making use of the fact that join puts delimiters between characters. (So not before first, and not after last).

This gives:

```
 ;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;\N;
```

Which I think matches your desired output?

As a oneliner, this would be:

```
perl -ne 'print join ( q{\N}, split // )'
```

Note - we need single quotes `'` rather than double around the `\N` so it doesn't get interpolated.

If you need to handle variable content (e.g. not just `;` ) you can add `grep` or `map` into the mix - I'd need some sample data to give you a useful answer there though.

> I use this for infile edit, the regexp suits me better

Following on from that - `perl` is quite clever. It allows you to do in place editing (if that's what you're referring to) without needing to stick with regular expressions.

Traditionally you might do

```
perl -i.bak -p -e 's/something/somethingelse/g' somefile
```

What this is doing is expanding out that out into a loop:

```
LINE: while (defined($_ = <ARGV>)) {
    s/someting/somethingelse/g;
}
continue {
    die "-p destination: $!\n" unless print $_;
}
```

E.g. what it's *actually* doing is:

- opening the file
- iterating it by lines
- transforming the line
- printing the new line

And with `-i` that print is redirected to the new file name.

You don't have to restrict yourself to `-p` though - anything that generates output will work in this way -  although bear in mind if it doesn't 'pass through' any lines that it doesn't modify (as a regular expression transform does) it'll lose data.

But you can definitely do:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'print join ( q{\N}, split // )'
```

And inplace edit - but it'll trip over on lines that *aren't* just `;;;;;` as your example.

So to avoid those:

```
perl -i.bak -ne 'if (m/;;;;/) { print join ( q{\N}, split // ) } else { print }'
```

Or perhaps more succinctly:

```
perl -i.bak -pe '$_ = join ( q{\N}, split // ) if m/;;;/'
```

Comment: nice solution as well, but as I use this for infile edit, the regexp suits me better.

Comment: Do you mean using `-i` to edit in place? Because you don't have to use regex to do that at all. Any output will work just fine.

Comment: yeah , this is what I'm doing, but its part of bigger script. So I'm using S^I switch inside

Comment: anyhow you really elaborated nicely on whole thing, I will try your hints for sure :)